# Replace HTML tags in rich text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making rich text editor for my project now i'm stuck at one point i'm replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` and `[b][/b]` with `<b></b>` and `[i][/i]` with `<i></i>`. Now i don't understand how to replace `[img src=location]` with `<img src=location>` and `[a href=url]` with `<a href=url>` . I hope you guys understand my question. I need this urgently . Thanks

Below Is My Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
#my_textarea{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: thin solid #000;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 150px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
#preview{
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: thin solid #000;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<script>
function formatText(tag) {
   var myTextArea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
   var myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value;
   var selected_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionStart, myTextArea.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(0, myTextArea.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionEnd, myTextAreaValue.length);
   myTextArea.value = before_txt + '[' + tag + ']' + selected_txt + '[/' + tag + ']' + after_txt;
}

function insertlink(){
   var linkurl = prompt("Enter the URL for this link:", "http://"); 
   var myTextArea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
   var myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value;
   var selected_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionStart, myTextArea.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(0, myTextArea.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionEnd, myTextAreaValue.length);
   if(linkurl != null)
   {
       myTextArea.value = before_txt + '<' + 'a href=' + linkurl + '>' + selected_txt + '</' + 'a' + '>' + after_txt;
   }
}

function insertimage(){
   var imgurl = prompt('Enter image location', ''); 
   var myTextArea = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
   var myTextAreaValue = myTextArea.value;
   var selected_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionStart, myTextArea.selectionEnd);
   var before_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(0, myTextArea.selectionStart);
   var after_txt = myTextAreaValue.substring(myTextArea.selectionEnd, myTextAreaValue.length);
   if(imgurl != null)
   {
       myTextArea.value = before_txt + '[' + 'img src=' + imgurl + ']' + selected_txt + after_txt;
   }
}

function preview() {
    var textbox , view ;
    textbox = document.getElementById('my_textarea');
    view = document.getElementById("preview");
    view.innerHTML = textbox.value.replace(/\</g, '&lt').replace(/\>/g, '&gt').replace(/\[b]/g, '<b>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</b>').replace(/\[i]/g, '<i>').replace(/\[\/i\]/g, '</i>')
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Bold" onClick="formatText ('b');" /> 
<input type="button" value="Italic" onClick="formatText ('i');" /> 
<input type="button" value="Image" onClick="insertimage();" /> 
<input type="button" value="Link" onClick="insertlink();" /><br />
<textarea name="my_textarea" id="my_textarea" style="width:300px;"></textarea><br><br>
<div id="preview"></div><br>
<button id="btn" onClick="preview();">Preview</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cfYWE/

Comment: You'd do that with a regex, and all you have to do is search for a bbcode regex, and you'll find one.

Comment: do you make demo of it ?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you can simply replace every bracket with an angle bracket.
Here's a function that does just that:

```
// Convert BBCode to HTML
function bbcodeToHtml(bbcode) {
    var html = bbcode;
    html = html.replace(/\[/gi, '<');
    html = html.replace(/\]/gi, '>');
    return html;
}

var bbcode = '[a href=url][img src=location][/img][/a]';

bbcodeToHtml(bbcode); // returns '<a href=url><img src=location></img></a>'
```

Comment: In my preview function i replace all `< >` with `&lt &gt` because of htmlentities and this function again replace `&lt &gt` with `< >`

Comment: Well, in that case, just convert the angle brackets to entities *before* running my `bbcodeToHtml()` function.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the example you are listing use regex

```
var exp = /\[(.*)\]/;
var text = '[img src=location]';
text.replace(exp, "<$1>") // returns <img src=location>
```

Comment: In my preview function i replace all `< >` with `&lt &gt` because of htmlentities and this function again replace `&lt &gt` with `< >`